# Probability of n successful outcomes from multiple unique events

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I made this example to show the principle I'm struggling to understand, but it's otherwise irrelevant. A person attempts four events where each trial is independent. The first trial, there's a 90% chance of a successful outcome, 80% chance on the second try, 70% for the third, and 60% on the fourth. (Any probabilities could be substituted for these, they aren't related).

It's easy for me to find the average number of successful outcomes the person will have: $.9+.8+.7+.6 = 3.0$, but if I was asked, "what's the probability that the person will have exactly n successful outcomes", I get lost because there's many ways you could get 3 successes, but each with its own probability. How would I calculate this? What I'm really looking for is a generalized equation/approach I could use that could find this for however many trials, whatever probabilities, and any number of desired successful outcomes.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/probability-distribution-for-different-probabilities

Comment: There are several approximations, simulations, and software solutions. It's a moderately messy problem. How about clarifying the 'principle' this is supposed to help you understand. Some answers might be more helpful than others for that.

Comment: @BruceET what I'm most focused on is what I wrote in the last sentence

Answer (score 1):

Just enumerate and hard work. For 4 events this is feasible. Otherwise, use a computer.

E.g. 2 successes for events $ABCD$ ($abcd$ for unsuccessful outcomes)

$AB$ successful ($cd$ not) = $.9*.8*.3*.4$ etc. Enumerate all possible combinations and add up the probabilities.